# How to access an unrecognized MP3 player

Tags: windows-vista, usb, mp3-player

I have a Genex MP3 player and when I switch it to storage mode and connect it to my computer I see a popup message informing me that the USB hardware is unrecognized. How do I get my computer to recognise the device correctly?

Comment: Do you know the product name of your mp3 player?

Comment: Details would be appreciated.

Comment: You're still basically asking "My car is broken, how can I fix it?" - we can give general help, but more information is probably needed.

Comment: What operating system as you using (i.e. Windows XP, Windows 7, Mac OS X, Ubuntu Linux)?

Answer (score 4):

Some players connect using a protocol called [Media Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) (MTP), which integrates well with [Windows Media Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player) (WMP) and makes for simpler synchronisation with DRM'ed files, but it won't work without a recent version of WMP.

Others use [mass storage device class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass-storage_device_class) (MSC), which loses some of MTP's DRM compatibility but allows you to access the files within [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer).

You may be able to switch your player between MTP and MSC, and I suspect you may have more success in MSC mode.

But again, it would help if you could post details of the player.

Answer (score 1):

You will sometimes see error messages such as these, and sometimes no response at all if the device access mode is set incorrectly. Look for a setting on the MP3 player called **[mass storage mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass-storage_device_class)** (MSC) (or similar). This will make the MP3 player function as a USB drive.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I have Transcend T.sonic 330 8GB. It worked fine both on Windows XP and 7, but on old machine with XP it just couldn't be recognized. I went to settins->MTP and changed there to USB mode. After this it works fine on old machine.